# common ratio of a geometric sequence formed from three terms of an arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The problem is to prove that if we have an arithmetic sequence and we choose $3$ numbers from it which form a geometric sequence as well, and also in the new geometric sequence these $3$ numbers are after each other with no gap, the common ratio ($r$) can be calculated like this:

$A(m),A(n)$ & $A(p)$ are the chosen numbers, so the common ratio is $= \dfrac{p-n}{n-m}$

Please help me prove it!

Here is the original question in Persian:

[image]

Comment: A good place to start is with the definition of the common ratio of a geometric sequence.  Also, did you mean that $m, n,$ and $p$ are the chosen terms of the arithmetic sequence?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I mean A(p) is the Pth number of an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: In that case, it seems to be that $r = \frac{A(p) - A(n)}{A(n) - A(m)}$, which I obtained by applying the definition of the common ratio of a geometric sequence.

Comment: No. A(p), A(n) and A(m) are the terms of an arithmetic sequence, but the common ratio of the geometric sequence will be p-n/n-m. How can I send you a picture of my textbook?

Comment: If you click on edit, click on the square with rounded corners showing a sun above a mountain range.  You can upload a link to an image of the question there.  Since you are new to the site, it will just be a link, but I can use the link to post the actual image.

Comment: I tried but it seems I can't upload image beqause there's less than 10 reputations. After all I wanted to share the image of the formula, but there wasn't any proof for that in my textbook

Comment: No, it's okay now. The picture is of my textbook and it's in Persian. The translation will be what I've written. https://ibb.co/GT7WftW

Comment: While I do not read Persian, I suspect that the author meant to write $$q = \frac{a_p - a_n}{a_n - a_m}$$ based on your translation of the question.  Ideally, another user who reads Persian will be able to clarify matters for us.

Comment: No. I've checked other books, and also my teacher taught that equation in the way you see in the picture.

Comment: Yes, I thought the question was simpler than it actually is.  The algebra is messy.  If you have made progress, you should type up what you have done and explain where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I have posted an answer.  However, the claim does not hold if the arithmetic sequence is constant.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, you helped me a lot!❤

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(a_k)$ be an arithmetic sequence with initial term $a_1$ and common difference $d$.  Then its $k$th term is given by $a_k = a_1 + d(k - 1)$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
a_m & = a_1 + d(m - 1)\\
a_n & = a_1 + d(n - 1)\\
a_p & = a_1 + d(p - 1)
\end{align*}
Since $a_m, a_n, a_p$ are successive terms of a geometric sequence with common ratio $r$,
$$r = \frac{a_p}{a_n} = \frac{a_n}{a_m}$$
since $r = \dfrac{a_{k + 1}}{a_k}$ for each positive number $k$.  Substituting for $a_m, a_n,$ and $a_p$ yields
$$r = \frac{a_1 + d(p - 1)}{a_1 + d(n - 1)} \tag{1}$$
and
$$r = \frac{a_1 + d(n - 1)}{a_1 + d(m - 1)} \tag{2}$$
If we multiply both sides of equation $1$ by $a_1 + d(n - 1)$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
ra_1 + rd(n - 1) & = a_1 + d(p - 1)\\
ra_1 + nrd - rd & = a_1 + pd - d \tag{3}\\
\end{align*}
If we multiply both sides of equation $2$ by $a_1 + d(m - 1)$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
ra_1 + rd(m - 1) & = a_1 + d(n - 1)\\
ra_1 + mrd - rd & = a_1 + nd - d \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Subtracting equation $4$ from equation $3$ yields
$$nrd - mrd = pd - nd$$
If $d \neq 0$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
nr - mr & = p - n\\
(n - m)r & = p - n\\
r & = \frac{p - n}{n - m}
\end{align*}
which is valid if the arithmetic sequence is not constant.

If $d = 0$, both sequences are constant, and the claim fails to hold.  For instance, let $(a_k)$ be the arithmetic sequence with $a_1 = 1$ and $d = 0$.  Then $a_k = 1$ for each positive integer $k$, so $a_1 = a_2 = a_6 = 1$ and $r = 1$, but
$$r = 1 \neq \frac{6 - 2}{2 - 1} = \frac{4}{1} = 4$$